# String Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have string similar to this but much longer: `a:'first'[as34ttatgv34tgw34t$'b':'man',a:'second'[sdfg53t3srthhghrs$'b':'woman'`

I want find pattern like, `a:'first'[SOMETHING1$'b':'SOMETHING2'` and replace SOMETHING2 to *caR* but SOMETHING1 remains unchanged

In result I got string:

```
a:'first'[as34ttatgv34tgw34t$'b':'caR',a:'second'[sdfg53t3srthhghrs$'b':'woman'
```

Comment: Can you better describe the pattern you want to identify? What type of assumptions can we make about the pattern you want to match?

Comment: I wanna find in string a:'first' and it is simply, next i wanna replace value 'b' of this a:'first'. 'b' is always behind pattern [SOMETHING$

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are looking to do.

Comment: I want replace all 'b':'' to other value but I dont know what kind of value is in 'b'. But I know value of a: its 'first' and I know that 'b' will be always behind pattern [SOMETHING$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match all the `b` values and replace them by using Positive Lookbehind `(?<=TEXT)` which is supported in Python. You can use this Regex if the `b` value contains only alphanumeric characters:

```
(?<=b\'\:\')[\w\s]*
```

Check out [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxB2vR/3)

If the `b value` is complicated and has special characters, you can match it using this regex:

```
(?<=b\'\:\')[\s\S]*?(?=\')
```

Here is a working Python of this replace using the second regex:

```
import re
text = '''a:'first'[as34ttatgv34tgw34t$'b':'man',a:'second'[sdfg53t3srthhghrs$'b':'woman'
'''
find = r"(?<=b\'\:\')[\s\S]*?(?=\')"
Bvalue = re.findall(find, text)
text = text.replace(Bvalue[0], 'car', 1)  #first b value
text = text.replace(Bvalue[1], 'chair', 1)  #second b value
print text
```

output:

```
a:'first'[as34ttatgv34tgw34t$'b':'car',a:'second'[sdfg53t3srthhghrs$'b':'chair'
```

Python [demo](http://ideone.com/7yab5V)

As you can see in the Python above, all you have to do is to use `text.replace` function to replace the `Bvalue`, `Bvalue[0]` refers to `b value` number 1, and `Bvalue[1]` refers to `b value` number 2, and so on.

Comment: I wanna replace 'b' by 'a' value, I need function which I enter for instance: ('second', 'new_value') and I got `a:'first'[as34ttatgv34tgw34t$'b':'man',a:'second'[sdfg53t3srthhghrs$'b':'new_value'` , how to do that with this regular expressions

Comment: @ŁukaszMleczko I updated my code. All you have to do now is to use this function: `text.replace(Bvalue[0], 'car', 1)` to replace the first `b value` and `Bvalue[1]` to replace the second `b value`, `Bvalue[2]` to replace the third `b value` and so on.

Comment: It is possible to search by using text for example I want find fridge and change his 'b' to speaker.
`a:'fridge'[as34ttatgv34tgw34t$'b':'man',a:'apple'[sdfg53t3srthhghrs$'b':'woman'`  to: `a:'fridge'[as34ttatgv34tgw34t$'b':'speaker',a:'apple'[sdfg53t3srthhghrs$'b':'woman'`

As i said, I want something like function which I got two arguments first is content of 'a' next is replace text for 'b' of this 'a'.